# Phonegap Facebook connect plugin settings

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, cordova

I'm using phonegap plugin to connect to facebook
this one : https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect

I'm confused about Facebook app settings, when I call FB.init() I get this error message:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

I edited Website with Facebook Login (site url) to : http:// localhost/ (without the space ofcourse I only added it because stackoverflow doesn't allow a link with 'localhost' in it) and I waited for several minutes (more than one day) for it to work but it's still not working.

any idea how can I get it to work ?

thanks

Comment: Did you try this version it might allow more customization. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: I noticed that the url it's attempting to send to facebook is file://android_assets/www/[file_name_here].  I haven't fixed the problem in my app yet, but when I changed the FB.init({}) code to match https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/blob/master/example/Simple/index.html the error went away.

Comment: ever fix this? having same issue...

Answer (score 4):

There are several settings which you need to set.
These settings worked for me for a Phonegap Build environment.

Under **Native Android App**:

- **package name:** the "widget id" you have in your config.xml (e.g. com.aaa.bbb)
- **class name:** the "widget id" with ".ProjectActivity" appended (e.g. com.aaa.bbb.ProjectActivity)
- **key hash:** generate the key hash using the android instructions. Facebook explains this at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/
- **facebook login:** enabled
- **deep linking:** disabled

Other steps:

- You don't need to set "Website with Facebook Login (site url) " to `http://localhost/` anymore.  If you have a real website (with facebook login), then that's the place to put the real website URL.
- Ensure sandbox mode is disabled

Comment: hi. thanks i've done all of this but its still not working. can u help? do you think it could be to do with .ProjectActivity as i have a main index.html instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Write this code in onDeviceReady after creating your application id on facebook


 FB.init({
            appId: "<your appId>",
            nativeInterface: CDV.FB
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

on facebook eit your app settings
set your "Website with Facebook Login" to

```
http://localhost/
```