# can't get facebook login to work on phonegap app using javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova, facebook-login

I created a new facebook app in developers.facebook.com and for the domain i entered my own domain eg www.sarahsexample.com and url http://sarahsexample.com

In my web application I am using the [facebook javascript sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) to enable facebook login on my app.

i uploaded my files to my domain www.sarahsexample.com to test it out. it worked perfect.

the actual plan though is to package these files up and build them into a phonegap app. so i tested this out using build.phonegap.com and downloading it to my phone and i get an error from facebook.

[image: trying to log in from phonegap app]

so i followed various suggestions that i found on the web. I tried entering http://localhost:8000/ for the url of my app on developers.facebook.com and localhost for the domain. I still get the same error.

So then i found this [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759110/phonegap-facebook-connect-plugin-settings) and so i added a platform within my facebook app for android. and I generated firstly a keystore file in command prompt and then a [release key hash](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash) which i then entered to the key hash place in my app settings on facebook. (my domain and key hash is blurred out for privacy) [image: my app settings on developers facebook]

in my config.xml file i have this:

```
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
            xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
            id        = "com.gxxxxxc.ip_app"
            version   = "1.0.0">
```

and also to allow access to all domains i have this:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

when using build.phonegap.com i also entered my keystore file here. [image: phonegap keystore file]

i still get the same error. I feel like i've exhausted all possibilities. I've seen this error is very common but any of the solutions i've tried haven't worked. your help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: the problem is creating key have u set redirect  url

Comment: @AnkushThakur is that in facebook login settings. i see there valid OAuth redirect URIs. I put http://localhost/ in there. is that correct?

Comment: ple sent me screen shot where is u set

Comment: hi thanks for your help. i am actually using a plugin now instead called phonegap-facebook-plugin. its working fine now with the url as localhost. :)

Comment: @AnkushThakur hey do you mind having a look at my other related question thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249570/what-oauth-redirect-uri-should-i-use-in-facebook-app-settings-for-my-phonegap-ap