# What OAuth redirect uri should I use in facebook app settings for my phonegap app?

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, oauth, facebook-login

I have facebook login functionality almost fully working within my app, except I am now stuck on what redirect uri to enter in the facebook app settings.

Information on my facebook app settings:

I have added a platform for Android and filled in the Package name, class name and added a debug key hash as we can see. 
I also have added website URL and App domain, however I'm not sure these are necessary as it is not a website as such (rather a phonegap app)
[image]

In the side menu under Products I have added Facebook Login. Within the Facebook Login settings I am wondering what redirect uri to enter? (see screenshot below)

I saw on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/) a suggestion to enter https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html as a redirect uri. I have tried this and not been successful. Do you have any advice please? thanks

[image]

Comment: i think u have used integration through inappbrower

Comment: the problem is in your setting

Comment: @AnkushThakur Thanks. Where in the settings?

Comment: have u set redirect  path

Comment: can u tell me which plugin u have used and can u show me ur code